# Remove bold from Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, bold

I don't want the bold font in the Table of Contents. I am using the `memoir` class (and the `dash` chapter style). Any suggestions?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please, next time add a MWE!

For your problem, this is a solution with the commands of the `memoir` class:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\chapterstyle{dash}

\renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalfont}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\chapter{A brief introduction}
\section{\TeX\ and friends}
\chapter{\TeX\ \& \LaTeX}
\section{My favourite class: \texttt{memoir}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks, I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Short question, short solution: The easiest way, unless there is no option within the memoir class, is to redefine the tableofcontents and disable any bold font within a `\begingroup...\endgroup`, i.e.

```
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\relax}
```

This solution does not rely on particular `memoir` commands or external packages.

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\let\LaTeXStandardTableOfContents\tableofcontents

\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
\begingroup%
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\relax}%
\LaTeXStandardTableOfContents%
\endgroup%
}%

\chapterstyle{dash}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section[First section]{First Section of 1st chapter}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{First Section of 2nd chapter}


\end{document}
```

### Example output

[image]

Comment: To the unknown downvoter: Thank you very much... it's very easy to downvote without explanation

Comment: I'm not the down-voter, but I think I can see why. Redefining lower-level commands like this often has drastic and unintended consequences, and sometimes it may not even solve the problem for any number of reasons. For example, if any relevant code was using the deprecated `\bf`, this code wouldn't work as is. It is a solution that isn't aligned with the spirit of LaTeX, basically amounting to clicking the button for bold to un-bold part of a document (rather than making a proper design choice). Hope that helps understand the possible reasoning :)

Comment: @SeanAllred: Not really, actually. If there are oldfashioned commands, my solution will not work, but then the class/package has to be revised anyway. In this case nothing bad happens, it will just show the usual behaviour! -- How do you think `tocloft` does achieve its functionality? Just definining new commands, that are not connected to the standard commands? -- No, it redefines low level commands or adds extra code to them. If I would downvote any solution that does a redefinition of a low-level command, I would have to do a lot of downvotes

Comment: This is appropriate for package code, but not appropriate on the document design level or the author level.  In the end, *everything* is resolved to primitives (`\kern`, `\def`, `\advance`, etc.); but I would be saddened to see these in a document side-by-side with content.

Comment: @SeanAllred: You're right about the `package` code, but if the class, a package does not provide a specific feature, one has to patch the commands. I did not look into the `memoir` class, as I never use it -- If I would have done, so I would have seen, that it obviously loads `tocloft`... But in fact, I am rather disappointed about cowardly downvoting before leaving a comment with a suggestion.

Comment: Lazy, definitely. Cowardly might be a bit harsh.  Maybe there was no time. Again, I'm not the downvoter, so there's only so much I can say. (Aside: at this point, there are much better ways to patch commands than letting and grouping.  Look into `xpatch`.)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, this is almost what I want. The only different is that I want "Contents" in bold. How can I do that?