# Bold font math in table of contents

Tags: math-mode, table-of-contents, amsmath, bm

I have this code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % showframe
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=0.33\baselineskip]{caption}

\captionsetup[table]{
    font=bf,
    size=normalsize,
    justification=centerlast,
    labelsep=newline
    }
\renewcommand\thetable{\Roman{table}}

\begin{document}
\listoftables
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\vspace{10ex}
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\sisetup{table-format=2.2, group-separator={,}, group-minimum-digits=4}
\caption{\large{Header that includes math like this: $\bm{t(\alpha)}$}}
\label{table:fundsummary}
\parbox{\linewidth}{\small{This table presents some very interesting and very fancy data, which I expect will provide me with at least two Nobel prizes.}\vspace{2ex}}
\medskip\small\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                l
                S[table-format=-2.2]
           *{6}{S}
                }
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Description}}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Variable}}&
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Averages}\\\cmidrule{3-7}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}&{Factor 1}&{Factor 2}&{Factor 3}&{Factor 4}&{Factor 5}\\\midrule
Section 1       &11.11 &22.22 &33.33   &44.44   &55.55  &66.66\\\midrule
Section 2\\
Section 2.2     &11.11 &22.22 &33.33   &44.44   &55.55  &66.66\\
Section 2.3     &11.11 &22.22 &33.33   &44.44   &55.55  &66.66\\
Section 2.4     &11.11 &22.22 &33.33   &44.44   &55.55  &66.66\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which produces this output

[image: Table]

My table header is in bold font, so for the tables I have, where math is included, I use the *\bm* package. However, I just noticed that the math symbol also appears as bold in the table of contents. Is there a way to keep the math symbol in bold font in the table header, but then set it to a normal font in the table of contents?

I have read [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196598/remove-bold-from-table-of-contents) question, but the solution seems to only work with the memoir class.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Off-topic: I believe it should be `*{5}{S}`, not `*{6}{S}`, in the definition of the columns of the `tabular*` environment.

Comment: @Mico: Noted, I'll get it changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the optional argument of `\caption` to contain the text that's supposed to show up in the table of contents (ToC). I.e., change

```
\caption{\large{Header that includes math like this: $\bm{t(\alpha)}$}}
```

to

```
\captionsetup{font={large,bf}} % repeat 'bf' from an earlier '\captionsetup' call
\caption[Header that includes math like this: $t(\alpha)$]% % optional arg. for ToC
        {Header that includes math like this: $\bm{t(\alpha)}$}
```

and recompile twice.

Note that since you're loading the `caption` package, it's better to change the caption's font size via a `\captionsetup` directive. Do also note that `\large` is a switch, i.e., it doesn't take an argument.

---

A full MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{font=bf,size=normalsize,
    justification=centerlast,labelsep=newline}
\renewcommand\thetable{\Roman{table}}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\listoftables

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\begin{table}[h]
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\captionsetup{skip=0.33\baselineskip,font={large,bf}}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\sisetup{table-format=2.2, group-separator={,}, 
         group-minimum-digits=4}
\caption[Header that includes math like this: $t(\alpha)$]
   {Header that includes math like this: $\bm{t(\alpha)}$}
\label{table:fundsummary}

\small 
This table presents some very interesting and very fancy data, 
which I expect will provide me with at least two Nobel prizes.

\medskip
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
        l S[table-format=-2.2] *{5}{S} }
\toprule
Description & {Variable} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Averages}\\
\cmidrule{3-7}
&&{Factor 1}&{Factor 2}&{Factor 3}&{Factor 4}&{Factor 5}\\
\midrule
Section 1  &-11.11 &22.22 &33.33 &44.44 &55.55 &66.66\\
\addlinespace
Section 2 \\
Section 2.2&-11.11 &22.22 &33.33 &44.44 &55.55 &66.66\\
Section 2.3&-11.11 &22.22 &33.33 &44.44 &55.55 &66.66\\
Section 2.4&-11.11 &22.22 &33.33 &44.44 &55.55 &66.66\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it solves it perfectly! I'll also look into the caption setup for the font size. Have a great weekend.

Answer (score 2):

While I prefer Mico's answer, one can also redefine `\bm` for the LOT.  Since `\bm` is protected, it will not be expanded in the aux or lot files.

BTW, for the MWE all you needed was the `\caption`, not the `tabular`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % showframe
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=0.33\baselineskip]{caption}

\captionsetup[table]{
    font=bf,
    size=normalsize,
    justification=centerlast,
    labelsep=newline
    }
\renewcommand\thetable{\Roman{table}}

\begin{document}
\bgroup
  \def\bm{}
  \listoftables
\egroup
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\vspace{10ex}
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\sisetup{table-format=2.2, group-separator={,}, group-minimum-digits=4}
\caption{\large{Header that includes math like this: $\bm{t(\alpha)}$}}
\label{table:fundsummary}
\parbox{\linewidth}{\small{This table presents some very interesting and very fancy data, which I expect will provide me with at least two Nobel prizes.}\vspace{2ex}}
\medskip\small\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                l
                S[table-format=-2.2]
           *{6}{S}
                }
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Description}}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Variable}}&
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Averages}\\\cmidrule{3-7}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}&{Factor 1}&{Factor 2}&{Factor 3}&{Factor 4}&{Factor 5}\\\midrule
Section 1       &11.11 &22.22 &33.33   &44.44   &55.55  &66.66\\\midrule
Section 2\\
Section 2.2     &11.11 &22.22 &33.33   &44.44   &55.55  &66.66\\
Section 2.3     &11.11 &22.22 &33.33   &44.44   &55.55  &66.66\\
Section 2.4     &11.11 &22.22 &33.33   &44.44   &55.55  &66.66\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Mr @JohnKormylo. Thank you very much for your answer as well.